# Data Reduction on 3d data

Tags: ios, 3d, cad, reduction, compression

We do start a project, where we have to try to reduce 3d CAD data (in size, in complexity,...) in such a way that it is possible to download it to a technicians phone/tablet with a 'slower' wifi connection.

So now I am searching for algortihms and/or techniques for this setting. As we have never worked with 3d data in general, we're open for all suggestions.

I can imagine something like compressing it on the server and downloading it afterwards, but this may prove not as useful, as you can't get the data neccesarily on the fly and you may need to compress everything beforehand. The same goes for the decompressing on the phone, which may take too long as well.
I think the optimal solution would be something like: we have an engine (for example) and we don't need every screw and every part but only a selection. For this we do some checkboxes and the server then only sends the required /checked components. I don't know if this is feasible, but I hope you can enlighten me on this topic.

Best regards!

Comment: What kind of 3d data we are talking about? Just triangle meshes or real 3D models such as IGES, STEP? How do you read in the 3d data on your server? What software are available on the technician's phone/tablet to view the 3d data?

Comment: AFAIK (and sadly as far as our company contact knows) they use CAD data with the *.jt-format. We are trying to get some more information right now.
The software on the technician's phone/tablet is going to be developed by us as well as how we read the data from the server, so we are pretty open for every idea/best practice there is.

Comment: If the CAD data is with JT format, then you should explore the possibility of using JT Open Toolkit for reading/writing JT files and JT2Go for viewing JT data on mobile devices.

Comment: i will check that out and we can use that as a reference at least, As this is a university project, we are required to program the front-/backend ourselves, so we cant just take this, but it will be a good start. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you are working with JT, what is an ISO standard, you can should have a look to the JT Ultra-Lightweight Precise (ULP) format.

If you have a converter that can be configure in this format, you'll certainly have the solution, otherwise, the JT Opentoolkit (not free, nor open source) is certainly the easiest way for you to generate the format.

You have in the JT file different "Level Of Details"(LOD). Understand it as simplification as: the geometry is stored many times in your file as with different precisions. You could profiting of it in order to generate your file with only acceptable LOD for your use case.

BRep can also be stored in a JT file. It is an matematically exact representation of the geometry. Do not store them in your JT file for visualization.

If you want to simplify the geometry, commercial solutions also exist. I won't recommand you to try to implement your own one solution.